# How to show yesterday previous messages in Earlier section using laravel 8?

Tags: laravel

I am new at laravel and I want to show all yesterday previous messages in Earlier section from new section how can i do that ? please help me thanks.

[image]

**Controller**

```
 public function index(){

        $userNotificationIds = UserNotification::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->pluck('notification_id');

        $data=[
            'userNotification' => Notification::whereIn('id',$userNotificationIds)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate(8),
        ];

        return view('web.user_notification',$data);
    }
```

**html view**

```
           <h4 class="fw-bold mb-3">New</h4>
              @if(count($userNotification) > 0)
                @foreach ($userNotification as $value)
                <div class="row notification rounded ">
                    <div class="d-flex pt-3">
                      <img class="rounded-circle" width="32px" height="32px" src="{{url('')}}/assets/web/img/profile-pic.png" alt="">
                      <div class="notification-text ms-3">
                        <span class="username fw-bold">Toby Ng</span>
                        <i class='bx bxs-circle small mx-2'></i>
                        <span class="text-muted">{{ $value->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</span>
                          <p class="mt-2"><span id="dots"> </span> {!! $value->description !!}</p>
                          <span class="text-primary fw-bold cursor-pointer" onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</span>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                @endforeach
              @endif
                    {{ $userNotification->links() }}
              <h4 class="fw-bold">Earlier</h4>
              <div class="row notification rounded">
                <div class="d-flex pt-3">
                  <img class="rounded-circle" width="32px" height="32px" src="img/avatar.png" alt="">
                  <div class="notification-text ms-3">
                    <span class="username fw-bold">Steven McNam</span>
                    <i class='bx bxs-circle small mx-2'></i>
                    <span class="text-muted">Yesterday</span>
                    <p class="mt-2">Welcome to WFH! Here is the link for you to get started. Please take your time to read it. <a href="#">https://www.google.com/</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can query for created_at less than or equal to yesterday

```
$earlier = Notification::whereIn('id',$userNotificationIds)->whereDate('created_at', '<=', \Illuminate\Support\Carbon::yesterday())->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate(8)
```